# Integer can not be cast to JsonNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

i got a cast error and have no idea how to solve that.

```
 //get my json file as Map
 Map<String, JsonNode> cm = null;
    try {
        cm = mapper.readValue(new File(path), Map.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {...} 
  //add some key, value pairs to my map

 JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
    ObjectNode node = factory.objectNode(); 
   //add to a jsonNode
  node.putAll(cm);
```

So I get an exception cause one of the key-value pairs looks like this: {"id":7}
and it seems like there is no way of converting the Integer(7) back to json even if it was one before.

Any Ideas?

The exeption:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be    cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not specify the type of your keys and values in your mapping:

```
mapper.readValue(new File(path), Map.class);
```

The result is that Jackson will try and map to the best type it knows; for the member name, it is easy, it's a `String`; for the value, it reads a JSON number, this JSON number has no decimal points, it fits into an `int` --> `Integer` it is.

If you want explicit serialization to a given value type, you have to do something like this:

```
mapper.readValue(new File(path), new TypeReference<Map<String, JsonNode>>() {});
```

Comment: Note that another solution, if you really want to read JSON, is just to deserialize as a `JsonNode` directly -- or even an `ObjectNode`

Comment: It's fine like that because i need the map to add key-value pairs and remove some :)

Comment: Well, `ObjectNode` has methods to remove key/value pairs from other `ObjectNode`s...